# Is MySqlBulkLoader sensitive to foreign keys?

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkinsert

I am using `MySqlBulkLoader` to bulk-insert a file into a table that has a foreign key constraint.

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
    bl.TableName = tableName;
    bl.Timeout = 600;
    bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
    bl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
    bl.FileName = tempFilePath;
    bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
    numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();
}
```

And file contents looks like this:

```
CampaignRunId,RecipientId,IsControlGroup
27,"testrecipient_0",False
27,"testrecipient_1",False
27,"testrecipient_2",False
27,"testrecipient_3",False
27,"testrecipient_4",False
27,"testrecipient_5",False
27,"testrecipient_6",False
27,"testrecipient_7",False
27,"testrecipient_8",False
27,"testrecipient_9",False
27,"testrecipient_10",False
27,"testrecipient_11",False
27,"testrecipient_12",False
27,"testrecipient_13",False
```

The `CampaignRunId` column is a FK that references another table `CampaignRun`'s Id column. The id `27` already exists in that table and when I use a single INSERT query directly on my MySql Workbench, the insert is successful. But from my program, this does not seem to work and I get the following `MySqlException`:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`postbag`.`campaignrecipient`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CampaignRecipient_CampaignRun` FOREIGN KEY (`CampaignRunId`)
>   REFERENCES `campaignrun` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Should I drop the foreign key before the insert and add them back after?

Comment: `set foreign_key_check=0` before you run your load. that'll disable FK enforcement until you quit that connection, or set the value to `1` again.

Comment: @MarcB but I am running the query from a program and this is not a one-off task. Is there a way to disable the foreign key check programmatically and reassign it back?

Comment: presumably that `conn` is just a regular mysql connection you can run queries on, so `conn->execute('set foreign_key_checks=0')` or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB makes sense. But what I want to know is that is it true that `MySqlBulkLoader` does not work when we have foreign keys?

Comment: depends on what you mean, "doesn't work". no query will work if it'd cause a foreign key violation. but there are MANY cases where a table structure has self-referential FK, which means even mysql couldn't load its own dumps. e.g. mysql_dump tends to spit out the dumps with the tables in alphabetical order. if a table `A` has a foreign key pointing at table `B`, then loading the dump would fail because table `B` won't have been loaded yet when the table `A` is being processed. hence the ability to temporarily disable FK checking.

Comment: @MarcB true. In my case, however, the FK constraint is not violated because the id already exists in the parent table.

Comment: well, something's causing a violation. maybe it's not skipping that first line and trying to insert the text `CampaignRunId`

Comment: @MarcB So I removed the `foreign_key_check` before doing the insert and the insert is successful, except that only one row is inserted and the first value of `CampaignRunId` in the file sits where my table's primary key Id is and the other columns are all shifted to left.